# The dynamics of stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I found that on stackoverflow, when a question is asked, especially when it is on a less obvious topic, often one person will post a reply that mostly misses the mark (I assume to get out some quick points or whatever) but that still gets the question to "answered" status.

I think that this will often lead to a question being overlooked...

How are the experiences of others on this? Are there systems in place to prevent this sort of thing? What can a question poster do to prevent this?

Comment: Note: it doesn't actually put the question in answered status unless it has an upvote.

Answer (score 6):

Answers are more likely to miss the mark when the question is vague or poorly worded. The best thing a poster can do to get an accurate answer is to post a specific and clear question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon B, but I have also experienced people answering my question with incorrect responses. I have carefully worded the question, and believe it to be as clear as I could make it. Other people responding correctly interpreted my question. In these cases I have responded quickly to their answers by editing my question to clarify whatever was mis-interpreted and commenting on their answers informing them of why I believe their answer is not useful and advising them to read the revised question.